# how to grab c array in python

Tags: python, c, arrays, ctypes

I have a C function:

```
void func(int n, int m)
{
    int Array[n][m];
    make_magic(Array);
}
```

which make 2D array and process it. I use this func in python3.5 with ctypes like this:

```
from ctypes import *

magic = CDLL('lib_name')
magic.func(n,m)
```

So how can I grab this 2D Array in python?

Comment: What array? The function does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to handle the c data types that are returned, but in your c function add a `return` statement. Then you can just:

```
array = magic.func(n,m)
```

Alternatively you can use swig to create a python wrapper module around your c code. Then you'll be able to call any function from it that you want directly in python.

Comment: C can return only scalars (int, bool, pointers, etc.) and, hence, no arrays. Furthermore, Python does not support arrays by default. However, even if both would be possible, the object structures of the near-memory C and the interpreted Python would probably be very different.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the generated array in Python, right?

Adopt your C-code to "return" the array via a received pointer.

```
void func(int n, int m, int *Array)
{
    Array[0][0] = 42;   // fill array accordingly
    make_magic(Array);
}
```

Initialize the array by NumPy, create & process it by your function, and post-process it with NumPy:

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy
n, m = 5, 10
array = numpy.zeros((n,m), dtype=numpy.int)
magic = CDLL('lib_name')
magic.func(n,m, array.ctypes.data)
```